# Como criar um novo arquivo .M3U corretamente? (Sendo que ja tenho o streaming .TS)

Tags: javascript, html5-video, reprodutor-de-video

Estou começando a estudar para fazer um site de aulas online (video ao vivo), mas os exemplos que estou usando da internet estão me dando os mais variados erros, conforme o exemplo que uso... 
Neste exemplo, ele fica carregando infinitamente...

**Hoje o arquivo que estou usando para estudar vem do seguinte site e preciso toca-lo no NAVEGADOR:** 
 `"http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"`

---

**Comecei assim:**

**Eis o arquivo "`exemplo.m3u`" que criei:**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:11167259
#EXTINF:10.000,
http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts?sd=10
#EXTINF:10.000,
http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts?sd=10
#EXTINF:10.000,
http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts?sd=10
```

**Para tocar estou usando  o jpayer:**

```
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
  playlist: [
    {
      sources: [
        {
        default: 'false',
            file: 'exemplo.m3u',
            label: '0',
            type: 'hls',
            preload: 'none'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  primary: 'html5',
  hlshtml: true
});
```

Bom ele fica carregando infinitamente, não consigo ver onde estou errando...

Answer (score 12):

#### TL;DR

> Use o [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org).

Para recriar o m3u8 a partir de apenas um arquivo .ts:

```
ffmpeg -i arquivo_original.ts -codec copy -hls_flags single_file -hls_list_size 0 nova_playlist.m3u8
```

O comando para multiplos arquivos é:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:arquivo0.ts|arquivo1.ts|arquivo2.ts|arquivo3.ts" -c copy -hls_list_size 0 nova_playlist.m3u8
```

> Ele gerará um novo arquivo .ts, que pode ser ignorado pois é uma cópia do original - isso que a opção `-c copy` faz. Removendo a opção faz com que ele "reencode" o vídeo.

---

#### Resposta longa - Por que o vídeo não toca?

O vídeo usado de exemplo: `San_Diego_Clip.ts`, está em `MPEG1/2`, [formato não suportado nos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). Ele provavelmente foi criado assim para ser consumido de outra forma, i.e. usando o [VLC](http://www.videolan.org).

Um segundo motivo para ele não tocar, é sua página não estar sendo servida do domínio onde o vídeo reside, por conta [da política de mesma origem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem).

> Por exemplo - a mesma página, aberta localmente, permite a visualização apenas do vídeo que está também local:

[image: screenshot do navegador]

> Aberta a partir do servidor, os dois vídeos tocam normalmente (note que o 'local' neste caso também é o servidor):

[image: screenshot do navegador]

O código usado para essas duas páginas foi exatamente o mesmo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Precisa de um título, blogueira!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <h3>Esse vídeo está no servidor:</h3>
        <video src="http://192.168.56.1/saida.m3u8" width="320" height="180" controls autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <h3>Este vídeo está local:</h3>
        <video src="saida_2.m3u8" width="320" height="180" controls autoplay></video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### A respeito do m3u:

O m3u é um arquivo de *playlist*, que tem muitas funcionalidades. Recriá-lo corretamente não é exatamente uma tarefa trivial.

Dito isso, para o exemplo mostrado acima, eu fiz um `m3u` extremamente simples:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXTINF:0,
saida_2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Veja:

- A maioria das informações de um m3u foram removidas;
- A duração do segmento está zerada;
- Eu usei um trecho do meio do vídeo;

O que significa que, na pior das hipóteses, é possível criar um m3u "na mão". O problema deve acontecer se os arquivos de vídeo forem **realmente** segmentados, e divididos de dez em dez segundos como alguns exemplos que se encontra por aí. De qualquer maneira, [nas especificações](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23.txt), é dito:

> *"Generally, durations SHOULD be decimal-floating-point, with enough accuracy to avoid perceptible error when segment durations are accumulated."*

Ou seja, colocar durações erradas pode causar *glitches*, mas não deveria impedir o vídeo de tocar.

#### Use o FFmpeg!

---

#### Resposta anterior:

O jwplayer parece só tocar HLS [usando contas premium](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference):

*Apple's HLS protocol, using M3U8 manifest files and TS media files. HLS builds upon standard HTTP, making it easy to deploy and firewall resilient. All JW Player editions support HLS on mobile devices, but only the Premium and higher support HLS on desktop browsers. See Using Apple HLS Streaming for more info.*

Para testar seu .M3U8, crie uma página com o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>precisa de um titulo, blogueira</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="saida.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

> Atenção: Tudo indica que esse código só funciona no Edge!

---

Para gerar um .M3U8, você pode usar o programa [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Baixe o arquivo e extraia em algum lugar de fácil acesso.
Acesse ele pelo prompt de comando, e digite o seguinte:

```
ffmpeg -i meu_video.mp4 saida.m3u8
```

*O FFmpeg aceita vários formatos de vídeo, mas sugiro que para teste você utilize um mp4 qualquer, gravado de celular, ou baixado da internet.*

> O resultado desse comando será vários arquivos .ts, e um arquivo .m3u8.

Teste utilizando o código mostrado acima:

[image: player de video em página html]

Fontes:
[Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)
[How to create byte-range m3u8 playlist for HLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497782/how-to-create-byte-range-m3u8-playlist-for-hls)
[HLS - how to create a m3u8 manifest if I have ts files (Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666717/hls-how-to-create-a-m3u8-manifest-if-i-have-ts-files-ubuntu)
[How to play html5 video play m3U8 on mobile and desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388135/how-to-play-html5-video-play-m3u8-on-mobile-and-desktop/23388308#23388308)
[FFmpeg - Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Me parece que  ela  não precisa criar novos Streaming, Ela  já tem o arquivo .TS sendo gerado... So  precisa exibir no navegador...   Que alias e meu problema também.

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 Você tem o arquivo .ts e não tem o arquivo .m3u8 correspondente?

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto editei minha resposta - por favor dê uma olhada! :)

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 resposta editada - não vejo muitas outras opções além desta... :( Boa sorte!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto espero que essa solução ajude vocês!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto não sei se ele foi descontinuado - [na página deles](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/) não parece dizer isso - e a última atualização na página foi bem recente. de qualquer modo, se você continuar tendo problema com ele, sugiro que você abra uma nova pergunta, pois está saindo do escopo desta... =]

Comment: @Blogueira voce sabe como  tocar o streaming "dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"; ??? __1) Hoje se coloco essa URL no navegador... ele pede pra salvar.. __2) se coloco no "web player" (jwplayer por exemplo) ele nao faz nada....

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto olá! então - ele está num formato não suportado nos browsers né - eu também não consegui tocar, não sei se é possível sem convertê-lo antes

Comment: mmm entendo, pena,   fiz varios testes, criando o **.M3U8**  ou ***.M3U**  local e tudo foi bem.. MAS como preciso tocar AQUELE, remoto.. do exemplo publico...  nao vai.. pois justamente falta o **.M3U** ... ___=> ENTAO tentai apontar o arquilo LOCAL **.M3U**   para o **.TS** remoto.. mas ai.. ele para..    BOM se tiver dicas ..  sobre como tocar o arquivo , remoto **.TS**  agradeco...  posi parece que tudo gira envolta de criar ao danado do **.M3U8**